# Aligning an iFrame's left edge to -100?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have an `iframe` placed in my body. However, I want to align it's left edge to -100px normally, and then on hover move it to 0px. However, I can find no way to do this. I tried using CSS:

```
.cnetBox {
    left:-100px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    opacity:.5;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

    .cnetBox:hover {
        left:0px;
        width:90%;
        height:500px;
        opacity:1;
    }
```

And then in the body:

```
<iframe src="http://www.cnet.com" height="200" width="200" class="cnetBox">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

But nothing happens. The iframe is still aligned only ever to the left edge at 0px. How can I set the left edge to -100px? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `position: relative` to your `.cnetBox`.

Your `iframe` (like all other elements) has it's position as `static` by default, and so providing any position values will have no effect. This [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/) article does a good job of explaining the differences without getting too verbose.

Alternatively, if for some reason you need the `iframe` to remain static, then swap `left` for `margin-left` and you'll achieve pretty much the same thing.

Comment: Oh, duh. Right thanks. Sorry for asking such basic questions. I'm used to full-blown languages. It's odd how much html, css, js does for you, but pretty neat. Anyway, I'll accept your answer as it allows me too.

Answer (score 2):

In order for the CSS `left`, `top`, etc to affect the position of an element, it must have a `position` set.

Depending on the structure of your HTML, you'll want a value of `relative` or `absolute`

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/VAqTt/

**Documentation and Related Reading**

- css `position` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position
- css `top` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/left
- *"Visual formatting model" on MDN* - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Visual_formatting_model
- "CSS Positioning 101" on alistapart*- http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101

Answer (score 2):

Add `position:absolute;` to your `.cnetBox CSS`

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/101/